# Is there a way in C# to constantly check throughout the run time of a program if a value is a specific number

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am making a game of monopoly in c# and i have a dice roll but when i try to change one picturebox's colour on the board which represents a square where the player can be it will not change or display a string telling the user they have landed on a community chest for example. Like in the image i have provided player 1 is currently at position 17 which is the community chest, the picture box on that square should turn blue and there should be an announcement where the 6 is displayed telling the user to click the community chest button.

[image]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((P1Pos == 2) || (P2Pos == 2) || (P3Pos == 2) || (P4Pos == 2)) && ((P1Pos == 17) || (P2Pos == 17) || (P3Pos == 17) || (P4Pos == 17)) && ((P1Pos == 33) || (P2Pos == 33) || (P3Pos == 33) || (P4Pos == 33)))
            {
                label13.Text = "You have landed on a community chest. Please click the chest button.".ToString();
            }
            Random rnd = new System.Random();
            int Dice = rnd.Next(1, 12);
            label14.Text = Dice.ToString();     //Rolling the dice

            if (CurrentPlayer == "Player 1")
            {
                label15.Text = (int.Parse(label15.Text) + Dice).ToString(); // Adding the roll number to the current piece position 
                P1Pos = int.Parse(label15.Text);
                if (P1Pos > 40)
                {
                    P1Pos = P1Pos - 40;
                    label15.Text = P1Pos.ToString(); // Checking if the piece is at 40 and taking 40 away as it is the biggest square number
                }

                CurrentPlayer = "Player 2";
                NextPlayer = "Player 3";
                return;
            }
            if (CurrentPlayer == "Player 2")
            {
                label22.Text = (int.Parse(label22.Text) + int.Parse(label14.Text)).ToString();
                P2Pos = int.Parse(label22.Text);
                if (P2Pos > 40)
                {
                    P2Pos = P2Pos - 40;
                    label22.Text = P2Pos.ToString(); // Checking if the piece is at 40 and taking 40 away as it is the biggest square number
                }
                CurrentPlayer = "Player 3";
                NextPlayer = "Player 4";
                return;
            }
            if (CurrentPlayer == "Player 3")
            {
                label16.Text = (int.Parse(label16.Text) + int.Parse(label14.Text)).ToString();
                P3Pos = int.Parse(label16.Text);
                if (P3Pos > 40)
                {
                    P3Pos = P3Pos - 40;
                    label16.Text = P2Pos.ToString(); // Checking if the piece is at 40 and taking 40 away as it is the biggest square number
                }
                CurrentPlayer = "Player 4";
                NextPlayer = "Player 1";
                return;
            }
            if (CurrentPlayer == "Player 4")
            {
                label21.Text = (int.Parse(label21.Text) + int.Parse(label14.Text)).ToString();
                P4Pos = int.Parse(label21.Text);
                if (P4Pos > 40)
                {
                    P4Pos = P4Pos - 40;
                    label21.Text = P4Pos.ToString(); // Checking if the piece is at 40 and taking 40 away as it is the biggest square number
                }
                CurrentPlayer = "Player 1";
                NextPlayer = "Player 2";
                return;
            }

            if (((P1Pos == 2) || (P2Pos == 2) || (P3Pos == 2) || (P4Pos == 2)) && ((P1Pos == 17) || (P2Pos == 17) || (P3Pos == 17) || (P4Pos == 17)) && ((P1Pos == 33) || (P2Pos == 33) || (P3Pos == 33) || (P4Pos == 33)))
            {
                label14.Text = "You have landed on a community chest. Please click the chest button.";
            }

            if ((P1Pos == 17) || (P2Pos == 17) || (P3Pos == 17) || (P4Pos == 17))
            {
                label14.Text = "You have landed on a community chest. Please click the chest button.";
            }
            if ((P1Pos == 33) || (P2Pos == 33) || (P3Pos == 33) || (P4Pos == 33))
            {
                label14.Text = "You have landed on a community chest. Please click the chest button.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself cutting and pasting code like that, ask yourself if there is a way to make a *method* that does that work which you can *call*.  That way you write the code once, which is understandable and maintainable, rather than several times, which is hard to read and prone to bugs.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you learn about separation of "model" -- that is, the facts about *the game* like players, money, properties, and so on, and "view" -- that is, the user interface elements that display the model.  You seem to be deeply conflating them, which will make it hard to write the game logic. Structure your code so that there are classes that *just* know the rules of monopoly; you can write test cases that test if you're implementing the rules without having to automate the UI.

Comment: This checks for community chest **before rolling the dice**. Also **after the move checks were finished for all players**. But there's no way those community chest conditional blocks will ever match when you want them to.

Comment: If your players have have a property "position", then you can trigger off any attempt to set that property to a specific value.  I would recommend refactoring your code so that your players are actual classes, and players is a List<Player>.  Player should have properties like Name, Position, Cash, OwnedProperties, etc.

Comment: You probably also want to change your dice roll, so that it is the sum of two random numbers between 1 and 6.  `var roll = rnd.Next(1,6) + rnd.Next(1,6); Players[CurrentPlayer].Position = (Players[CurrentPlayer].Position + roll) % 40;`

Comment: And then have the Player class have events, like NameChanged, PositionChanged, CashChanged.  Then your main code can hook up event listeners for those events, and update the appropriate labels.  Again, I'd suggest a separate, but similar set up where you have a list of PlayerUiControls, and those have properies like NameLabel, MoneyLabel, PositionLabel.  A simple event listener could then look like: `public void PositionChanged(Player player) { PlayerUiControls.First(p=>p.Player == p).PositionLabel = p.Position.ToString(); }`

Comment: Not looking at your code but only at the tilte: That is what we have properties for! Simply code the check in the setter!

Comment: @RobertMcKee - That should be `var roll = rnd.Next(1, 7);` as the upper bound is exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Have classes like this:

```
public class Property
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Color {get;set;}
   public int PurchasePrice {get;set;}

   //other things like houses/hotel, mortgage, rent, etc
}

public class Player
{
    public Label positionLabel {get; set;}

    private int _position = 0;
    public int Position 
    {
       get {return _position;}
       set {
           _position = value;
           while (_position >= 40) position -= 40;
           while (_position < 0) _position += 40; //allow for moving backwards past Go
           if (positionLabel is object) 
               positionLabel.Text = _postition.ToString();
       }
    }

    public string PlayerName {get;set;}

    public int Cash {get;set;} = 1500;

    public List<Property> Properties {get;} = new List<Property>();
}
```

And then somewhere early on have code like this:

```
Player[] players = new Player[4];
for(int i = 0; i<4;i++)
{
    players[i] = new Player() {PlayerName = $"Player {i+1}"};
}
players[0].positionLabel = label15;
players[1].positionLabel = label22;
players[2].positionLabel = label16;
players[3].positionLabel = label21;

Random rnd = new System.Random(); //re-use the same random instance through the game!
int CurrentPlayer = 0; // now current player can just be an int index into the array
```

and then you can simplify the button_Click like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var player = players[CurrentPlayer];

    //rnd.Next() upper bound is **exclusive**.
    // Also, two rolls from 1-6 produce a different distribution
    //  than one roll from 1-12.
    int Dice = rnd.Next(1, 7) + rnd.Next(1, 7);
    label14.Text = Dice.ToString(); 

    player.Position += Dice;

    //community chest at board positions 2, 17, and 33.
    if (player.Position == 2 || player.Position == 17 || player.Position == 33) 
    {
        label14.Text = "You have landed on a community chest. Please click the chest button.";
    }

    CurrentPlayer++;
    if (CurrentPlayer >= players.Length) 
        CurrentPlayer = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a really good answer, except I wouldn't tie a Label into the Player class and instead have the Player class raise an event that the UI can listen for and modify itself.  Otherwise, you are coupling a UI-centric control (Label) to a "business" class, which you should try to avoid whenever possible.

Comment: And of course `_position = value; while (_position >= 40) position -= 40;` can be changed to `_position = value % 40;`

Comment: @RobertMcKee Except, of course, it should not be changed to that because in C#, `-55 % 40 == -15`.

Comment: @Joker_vD -55 and -15 are the same position, and both values would be quickly adjusted to 25 in the next line, which reads `while (_position < 0) _position += 40;`

Comment: And if you knew that you could never be moved back more than 40 spaces at a time (which you can not in monopoly), then you could replace `_position = value; while (_position >= 40) position -= 40; while (_position < 0) _position += 40; ` with  `_position = (value + 40) % 40;` but I didn't recommend that based on readability.

Comment: @RobertMcKee And so the code ends in the "cute arithmetics tricks for showing off intellectual superiority while being mostly irrelevant for performance" area. The original code is quite readable, has clear intent, and is just as fast.